# The set of all perfect numbers, amicable pairs, sociable triples of order three, four, etc..., is that set infinite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

After I have read (though not carefully) some pages about sociable numbers I thought that it would be convenient to ask a question that I "arrived at".

If we denote with $S_k$ the set of all sociable numbers of order $k$, that is, the set of all sociable $k$-tuples, then, for example, $S_1$ is the set of all perfect numbers and $S_2$ is the set of all amicable pairs.

From what I have read I concluded that, of course, it is not known which of the sets $S_k$ are infinite (some are even conjectured to be empty) and it is also stated that "It is an open question whether all numbers end up at either a sociable number or at a prime (and hence 1), or, equivalently, whether there exist numbers whose aliquot sequence never terminates, and hence grows without bound.".

But, although this question maybe is a silly one (if there is something obvious of I am not aware of), I would like to know is it at least known is the set $S=\bigcup_{k=1}^{+ \infty}S_k$ infinite?

The set $S$ is clearly infinite if at least one of the sets $S_k$ is infinite (and I think that is not known as of this moment) or if at least an infinite number of sets whose union is $S$ contain at least one member.

What are your thoughts about this, is $S$ known to be infinite?

Comment: It is conjectured that infinite many perfect numbers exist.

Comment: @Peter Yes it is, but even if there are finitely many of them $S$ can be infinite even in that case.

Comment: I know, I think this is wide open. Intuitively, I would assume that the other $S_k$ are finite, but maybe, I am wrong. What does Wikipedia say about social numbers and what about amicable numbers ?

Comment: @Peter I think that infinitely many of $S_k$ are infinite and that I am wrong.

Comment: any sum of divisors has a maximum number of distinct divisors possible $T_n<x<T_{n+1}$ implies $x$ is the sum of divisors of a number with no more than $n$  divisors.